# JPA/Hibernate problema com concorrência e persistência no JRE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Estou trabalhando em projeto para criar um servidor simples rodando sobre Java SE. Estou usando JPA + Hibernate para realizar a persistência, porém as rotinas concorrentes são um problema. Estou perdendo muito tempo tentando resolver os problemas gerados pelo Hibernate sem ter um retorno significativo. Gostaria de saber dos caros colegas soluções já existentes para resolver os problemas de concorrência Java SE, como o *container-managed* `EntityManager` do J2EE.

Problemas:

- Sempre fechar o `EntityManager`.
- Instâncias de objetos divergentes em instâncias de `EntityManager` diferentes.
- Operações concorrentes com `EntityManager` diferentes gerando erro de persistência.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos começar com estes dois itens:

> - Instâncias de objetos divergentes em instâncias de `EntityManager` diferentes.
> - Operações concorrentes com `EntityManager` diferentes gerando erro de persistência.

NUNCA use um mesmo `EntityManager` em threads diferentes. O `EntityManager` foi projetado para viver e morrer confinado dentro da thread que o criou.

Recomendo estudar como efetuar o [`lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#lock(java.lang.Object,javax.persistence.LockModeType)) de entitdades. Vale a pena dar uma estudada nos conceitos de lock otimista (*optimistic lock*) e lock pessimista (*pessimistic lock*). Nos lugares aonde preferir o lock otimista, lembre-se da anotação [`@Version`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html). Não vou entrar em maiores detalhes aqui, porque isso daria para escrever alguns capítulos de livros e a ideia é apenas te mostrar qual é o caminho para encontrar o que você quer.

Além disso, vale lembrar que cada instância de uma entidade só pode ser gerenciada por um único `EntityManager`, e por causa disso não é correto compartilhar estas instâncias entre diversos `EntityManager`s, o que também significa que você tem que ter bastante cuidado se for compartilhá-las em mais de uma thread. Uma forma de fazer isso é mais ou menos assim:

```
MinhaEntidade veioDeOutraThread = ...;
MinhaEntidade minhaEntidadeNestaThread = em.find(MinhaEntidade.class, veioDeOutraThread.getId());
```

Uma forma segura de trabalhar com isso seria você nunca compartilhar qualquer objeto que seja tocado pelo JPA entre diferentes threads que possam acessar o banco de dados diretamente.

> - Sempre fechar o `EntityManager`.

O mais óbvio é usar o velho `try-finally`, mas talvez você queira algo mais mágico. Neste caso posso te sugerir partir de algo mais ou menos assim (Java 8):

```
 private static final EntityManagerFactory EMF = ...;

 private final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> ativo = new ThreadLocal<>();

 public <E> E transact(Function<EntityManager, E> func) {
     EntityManager em = ativo.get();
     if (em != null) return func.apply(em);
     em = EMF.createEntityManager();
     try {
         ativo.set(em);
         boolean success = false;
         EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
         try {
             et.begin();
             E ret = func.apply(em);
             success = !et.getRollbackOnly();
             return ret;
         } finally {
             if (et.isActive()) {
                 if (success) {
                     et.commit();
                 } else {
                     et.rollback();
                 }
             }
         }
     } finally {
         ativo.set(null);
         em.close();
     }
 }
```

Se estiver usando Java 7 ou inferior, não deverá ser muito difícil adaptar este código para as suas necessidades. Se você tiver a intenção de fazer o seu método `transact` lançar alguma exceção verificada, então o melhor a fazer é usar uma interface funcional customizada.

Este código acima pode ser melhorado de forma a evitar que o `EntityManager` fosse recriado múltiplas vezes na mesma `Thread` se você não fechá-lo e utilizar um `em.clear()` antes de iniciar alguma operação e/ou depois de terminá-las. Entretanto, se isto não for feito de uma forma bem precisa, pode introduzir bugs de concorrência na aplicação, enquanto que abrindo e fechando várias vezes do jeito que está, no máximo prejudica um pouquinho a performance.

Além disso, talvez você perceba que o código acima emula a semântica do escopo de transação *required* do EJB/Java EE (pelo menos eu acho que emula, a menos que eu tenha feito alguma besteira ou esquecido alguma coisa). Não é muito difícil modificá-lo para emular outros escopos tais como *requires new*, *mandatory*, etc.